# When editing a CSS file in Visual Studio 2019, is there a way to see if a class is part of a media query?

Tags: css, visual-studio, visual-studio-2019

When working with large CSS files I often find myself trying to determine if the class I am editing is global or media query specific. But when I hover over a class the only info I get is 'selector specify'. So if I need to know if it's part of a media query I have to either search or scroll up (sometimes a long way) to figure it out. Is there an easier way to see if the class belongs to a media query?

[image: visual studio 2019 css text editor]

**Note:** I know it is now more common to keep classes together, with their media queries immediately after the global style. Some of the CSS I am working with is a bit older, so there is a single media query for each breakpoint at the end of the file. Thus, I can be on line 4200 and there is no way to quickly conclude if the class is part of a media query.

Comment: If it’s not SCSS, you can tell based on whether it’s indented.

Comment: There's nothing built-in. You can use the map mode of the scroll bar and show the Preview Tooltip, then you can see where the indentation starts and see if it's a media query. I expect there's probably an Add-In that helps...If not, a great opportunity to build one! :)

Comment: @HereticMonkey Yeah, I tried the preview but it didn't do much for me. I did also check the extension marketplace but nothing exists. I was very surprised by this. It seems there are way more options for VS Code, which, of course, doesn't help me any.